# How to wait a certain interval, then check for user activity and fire code and start waiting again?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, timing

On page load, we should wait 15 seconds and then start checking for user activity in the form of mouse movement. If there is user activity, fire code and start waiting 15 seconds for user activity again.

My best shot is below. I have made an interval that gives permission to check every 15 seconds, and another interval that checks for permission and tries to fire the code on first mouse movement, then reset permission -- every second.

The initial check is correct (it waits 15 seconds and doesn't fire until the mouse moves), but then the code keeps firing every 15 seconds regardless of user activity -- though oddly enough only when the window is in focus. I suspect my error is in the mousemove bit, but I'm not sure.

```
var allow = false;
setInterval(permission, 15000);
function permission() {     
    if (allow == false){
        allow = true;
    }
}

setInterval(function() {
    $('body').one('mousemove', function() {
        if (allow == true){
            alert("code firing");
            allow = false;
            $('body').off( "mousemove" )
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setTimeout` for this, because the interval you need is not constant: you don't know when the user will move their mouse and the 15 second period should start from 0 again.

Here is a demo with 3 second waits (to test it quickly):

```js
var allow;
function lockUp() {
    allow = false;
    $('#output').text("No permission for 3 seconds!");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#output').text("Permission!");
        allow = true;
    }, 3000);
}

// start by locking for 3 secs    
lockUp();

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (!allow) return; // not allowed
    lockUp();
    // Perform the action here...
    // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This one seems to work most predictably. My brain turns into spaghetti when I have to work with timers! Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep track of the last mouse move.

```
var lastMove = new Date(); // assume last move was now

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
  lastMove = new Date();
});

setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date();

    // compare dates in milliseconds to see if the difference is greater than 15000
    if (currentTime.getTime() - lastMove.getTime() >= 15000) {
        // if it's greater, trigger your code
    }
}, 5000); // perform this check every 5 seconds
```

I perform the check every 5 seconds so that the maximum possible delay would be 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove the second `setInterval`.

Your first `setInterval` correctly sets `allow` to **true** every 15 seconds.

```
on('mousemove', function() {
    if(allow){
          // do stuff
          allow = false;
    }
});
```

This part triggers whenever the mouse is moved. But it takes only effect when `allow` is **true**. So that is actually what you want. Since allow is set to **true** every 15 seconds, you will have your stuff done only every 15 seconds (of course only if the mouse is moved).

Of course it is important, that you set `allow` to **false** after you did your stuff.

Comment: I think this is the block of code I was trying to write all day, but I got stuck in a conceptual box about timers. Thanks for this!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to hold up if you wait longer than 15 seconds. The code can fire twice quickly before the timer kicks in again :/

Comment: Try to set `allow = false` as the first thing inside the **if**. I'm not sure if this will help, but I think it's worth a try.